# How to use one Page object in multiple Frames in another Page?

Tags: c#, wpf, frame

I want to have a Page object, that contains Frames, that contain another Page. The current result looks like that:
[image]
But I want the Page to be appear in all of the Frames.
How can I achieve that?
The page that contains Frames:

```cs
public partial class CombinedPage : Page
{
    public CombinedPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Frame1.Content = MainWindow.testPage;
        Frame2.Content = MainWindow.testPage;
        Frame3.Content = MainWindow.testPage;
        Frame4.Content = MainWindow.testPage;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Width="5" Background="Black"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="5" Background="Black"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />

    <Frame NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" x:Name="Frame1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Frame NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" x:Name="Frame2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <Frame NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" x:Name="Frame3" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Frame NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" x:Name="Frame4" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"/>
</Grid>
```

The `TestPage` XAML:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Label  Name="LiveTimeLabel" Content="%TIME%" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="#cccccc" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontWeight="Bold" />
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

Thanks for any advice!

**EDIT 1:** Ok, then if I can use Page object only once, then how change it's location from one frame to another? I tried this, but it doesn't seem to be work:

```cs
public partial class CombinedPage : Page
{
    public CombinedPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Frame1.Content = MainWindow.testPage;
        Frame2.Content = MainWindow.testPage;
        Frame3.Content = MainWindow.testPage;
        Frame4.Content = MainWindow.testPage;
    }

    private void butt1_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame1.Content = MainWindow.testPage;
    }

    private void butt2_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame2.Content = MainWindow.testPage;
    }

    private void butt3_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame3.Content = MainWindow.testPage;
    }

    private void butt4_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame4.Content = MainWindow.testPage;
    }
}
```

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Width="5" Background="Black"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="5" Background="Black"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />

    <Frame NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" x:Name="Frame1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Frame NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" x:Name="Frame2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <Frame NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" x:Name="Frame3" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Frame NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" x:Name="Frame4" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button x:Name="butt1" Width="50" Click="butt1_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="butt2" Width="50" Click="butt2_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="butt3" Width="50" Click="butt3_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="butt4" Width="50" Click="butt4_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create separate instance of the same `Page` class:

```
public CombinedPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Frame1.Content = new TestPage();
    Frame2.Content = new TestPage();
    Frame3.Content = new TestPage();
    Frame4.Content = new TestPage();
}
```

A single instance of a control can only appear *once*  in the visual tree so you cannot display the same page instance in more than one `Frame`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I know this. And the question was - How to use **one** Page object.... So I really have to use only one object. And I want to know is there any way to do this.

Comment: I though I answered that. The answer is no. A single instance of a control can only appear once in the visual tree.

Comment: Ok, @mm8, but then how to change the location of the object between frames? I updated the question

Comment: Please ask a new question instead of changing the original one.

Comment: But you could try to set the `Content` of the other frames to `null` or something else.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will mark it as the solution when it will be possible. Now I have another problem :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70037443/why-does-page-disappears-when-i-move-it-between-frames