# Why does Page disappears when I move it between frames?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, frame

I have a window with a *Main* frame which contains a Page. And I have another Page that contains the first Page. And I want to move between this two Pages. Here is the first page:
[image]
And the second one:
[image]
Everything is ok for the first time when I run the app. But when I come back to the first Page and then to the second, the first Page in the second Page's frame disappears:
[image]
Here is the **MainWindow.xaml.cs**:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static TestPage testPage = new TestPage();
    public static CombinedPage combinedPage = new CombinedPage();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Butt1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        combinedPage.TimerFrame.Content = null;
        Main.Content = testPage;
    }

    private void Butt2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Main.Content = null;
        combinedPage.Call();
        Main.Content = combinedPage;
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="80 px"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="70 px" ></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" ></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Button x:Name="Butt1" Height="50" Width="50" Click="Butt1_Click"  />
        <Button x:Name="Butt2" Height="50" Width="50" Click="Butt2_Click"  />
    </StackPanel>
    <Frame NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" x:Name="Main" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

**CombinedPage.xaml.cs**:

```cs
public partial class CombinedPage : Page
{
    public CombinedPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Call()
    {
        TimerFrame.Content = MainWindow.testPage;
    }
}
```

**CombinedPage.xaml**:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Width="5" Background="Black"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="5" Background="Black"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />

    <Frame NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" x:Name="TimerFrame" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
</Grid>
```

So the final question is - Why does the first Page disappear when I move between pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm actuall using the `Frame` quiet rarily. It's a very heavy control that is only recommended when you want to display web content.
I highly recommend to use a `ContentControl` and a `DataTemplate` for each page/view.
See this example: [C# WPF Navigation Between Pages (Views)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61323201/3141792).
Using the suggested solution makes navigation more convenient. It eliminates isues like yours. Additionally, you have more options to customize the page navigation like adding animations.

The issue is that the `Frame` implements a special navigation flow. Setting the `Frame.Source` or `Frame.Content` property does not immediately completes the navigation i.e. the destination `Page` value is not immediately applied:

[image]
(Source: [Microsoft Docs: Navigation Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/navigation-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8))

As you can learn from the diagramm, setting the `Frame.Source` or `Frame.Content` results in a series of events that ends with the `LoadCompleted` event.
You are currently navigating to pages too early. The `testPage` is still loaded in the recent `Frame` and is therefore not able to be displayed in the next `Frame`.

The special problem with your scenario is that you want to load the same `Page` instance in different `Frame` instances. Since the `Page` instance can only be rendered once, you must unload the `Page` instance from the recent `Frame` in order to show it in the next `Frame`.

To fix your problem you have two options:

1. Handle the `LoadCompleted` event after the `null` assignment/`Frame` reset and set the new `Page` from the handler.
2. Use the `Dispatcher` with a priority of at least `DispatcherPriority.Background` to defer the assignment after the `null` assignment/`Frame` reset. For example:

   ```
   Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => Main.Navigate(testPage), DispatcherPriority.Background);
   ```

I recommend handling the `LoadCompleted` event as the behavior is definitely more deterministic:

```
private void Butt1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  combinedPage.TimerFrame.LoadCompleted += SetMainFrame_OnLoadCompleted;
  combinedPage.TimerFrame.Navigate(null);
}

private void SetMainFrame_OnLoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  combinedPage.TimerFrame.LoadCompleted -= SetMainFrame_OnLoadCompleted;
  Main.Navigate(testPage);
}

private void Butt2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Main.LoadCompleted += SetFrameContents_OnLoadCompleted;
  Main.Navigate(null);
}

private void SetFrameContents_OnLoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  Main.LoadCompleted -= SetFrameContents_OnLoadCompleted;
  combinedPage.Call();
  Main.Navigate(combinedPage);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for so good answer. I read about ```DataTemplate ``` and understoos that it is too difficult for me. So I took your code with ```LoadCompleted```, changed it a bit and it's works as I wanted. Thanks again!